# How to order 2 columns by today's date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort rows of data based on whatever today's date is within excel. What I would like is for rows to be sorted so that only rows that contain a date within the next 8 weeks within columns U and V are shown after a click of the button "Show next 8 weeks".

Basically when I click the button, I would like excel to only show me sites that have a site start or site end date within the next 8 weeks. thanks, I am a total excel/vba noob so really appreciate the help!

[The spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmkrP.png)

Comment: Post your tries (your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
Dim d As Date
d = Now + 56

With ActiveSheet
    If .FilterMode = False Then
        .Columns(22).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & d
    Else
        Columns(22).AutoFilter
    End If
End With
```

Comment: thanks Brian! do you also know how I could undo this so it shows all rows again? sort of like a reset.

Comment: `.AutoFilter Field:=1` is the line that resets it. But it sounds like you want to activate and reset by clicking each time. I'll need to change the macro for that.

Comment: thanks a lot, yeah the spreadsheet is going to be constantly updated. That's why I'd like a button to just show the next 8 weeks but also have a way to show all rows when I need to :)

Comment: @JakeMilligan See my `EDIT` above. It will enable you to turn the filter on/off with one click.

Comment: the clearing of the filter works perfectly but for some reason the actual 8 week filter itself isn't working. I have changed the site start/ end dates in order to test the filter out so that some rows should be shown and others should not however when i click the button, it "hides" every row and doesn't show me anything at all.

Comment: Not sure. It worked for me. Try an easier version above.